# Tomcat decrypt aes different from Java Main application

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have an AES encrypted byte array. When I decrypt this array in java application, everything is fine. But in a servlet container, decrypted wrong.

Here ise my byte array

```
       String [] str = new String[] {"41", "23", "67" ,"-124", "-56" ,"-35" ,"89", "-54" ,"-17" ,"-49" ,"-53", "-21" ,"125" ,"4", "98", "-13", "60" ,"-72", "12", "75" ,"-105" ,"-104", "107", "34", "1", "-109", "-19", "-102", "-72", "9" ,"26" ,"-39", "-60", "-15", "0" ,"112", "-5", "-86", "-7", "5" ,"75", "100" ,"94", "-47", "6", "-81", "-22", "82", "97" ,"114", "3", "-24", "-80", "67", "106", "-100" ,"-35", "-83", "54", "-95", "124", "-22", "-100", "-47" };

        byte [] inv = new byte[str.length];

        int count = 0;
        for (String s : str) {
            inv[count++] = Byte.valueOf(s);
        }
```

The result of Java Application

```
Decrypted: 000000.016*kWh|000000.007*kWh|000000.015*kWh|000000.000*kWh
```

My application code

```
 byte[] keyBytes = "vikoAmrPass12345".getBytes(); 
 SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES"); 
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding"); 
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key); 
 byte [] out = cipher.doFinal(inv); 
 System.out.println("Decrypted: " +new String(out));
```

My web code which is works on servlet container is definitly same with above one. 
But the container decypted result is

```
'?f ??0??????b]5hJ?F*`U????.8??p@?]?u?~Nb??z?????{3??;?
```

What is wrong here ?

In my application, I got encrypted byte array as

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServetSocket(port); 
Socket socket = ss.accept(); 
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream(); 
byte [] sizeBuffer = new byte[5]; 
in.read(sizeBuffer); 
byte [] dataBuffer = new byte[Integer.valueOf(""+new String(sizeBuffer)];     
in.read(dataBuffer);
```

Encrypted data exists on *dataBuffer* array. And encryption handled in an embedded device.

My configuration

java 1.6
tomcat 7.1

Thanks.

Comment: Please show *all* the details of your decryption. (And also, why are you putting all your byte values into strings? Why not just declare `byte[] inv = { 41, 23, 67 } ..."?

Comment: byte[] keyBytes = "vikoAmrPass12345".getBytes();
     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
     cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
     byte [] out = cipher.doFinal(inv);
     System.out.println("Decrypted: " +new String(out));

Comment: Don't put that in a comment Beyt, please edit your question instead.

Comment: You should not use ECB encoding as it is insecure, and you should pad your data too. Try using `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` with a fully random IV instead.

Comment: @owlstead thanks for attention. I have edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've posted:

```
byte[] keyBytes = "vikoAmrPass12345".getBytes();
```

That *could* be the problem. You should never use the platform default encoding if you're expecting to get the same result in multiple places. Always specify the encoding.

If you've done this, it's *also* possible that you've got problems with how you're transporting the encrypted data. If you're ever creating a string from it, you should almost certainly use Base64, e.g. with [this library](http://iharder.net/base64). If you're using:

```
// Bad! Do not use!
String encryptedText = new String(encryptedData);
```

Then that will basically be losing information, and could well be the cause of the problem.

EDIT: Okay, so now we know your receiving code is:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServetSocket(port);
Socket socket = ss.accept();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
byte [] sizeBuffer = new byte[5];
in.read(sizeBuffer);
byte [] dataBuffer = new byte[Integer.valueOf(""+new String(sizeBuffer)]; 
in.read(dataBuffer);
```

Here you have at least three problems:

- Your code cannot possibly handle more than 99999 bytes, and it's not clear how you would expect it to handle less than 10000 bytes.
- You're assuming the default character encoding is consistent across platforms yet again
- Your code *assumes* that each time it calls `read`, that exact amount of information will be read. There's a good chance it won't, particularly for network streams. You should be using the return value of `read` to see how much has *actually* been read. You either need to loop round until you've read all the data required (or run out of data in the stream), or use a higher level API to do the same thing.

Comment: Hi, encrypted data is transporting via tcp/ip. And encrypted in an embedded device, decrypting in java application.

Comment: @Beyt: "Via TCP/IP" doesn't give much detail. Please show *exactly* show you're sending and receiving the data.

Comment: ServerSocket ss = new ServetSocket(port);  Socket socket = ss.accept();  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();  byte [] sizeBuffer = new byte[5];  in.read(sizeBuffer);  byte [] dataBuffer = new byte[Integer.valueOf(""+new String(sizeBuffer)];   in.read(dataBuffer);  I got encrypted data in **dataBuffer**

Comment: Thanks. Problem is about platform encoding. The secret key encodes bytes different on different platforms

Comment: @Beyt: Well, it's about more than that - it's about trying to represent *fundamentally binary data* in text in an inappropriate way.